# Spark - Mysql connection - Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 error

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I am trying to extract `MySQL` data through `Spark` but unfortunately I am getting below error. Here is my sample RDD :

```
emp_df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url",url).option("dbtable","employee").option("driver", 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver').load()
```

Error :

```
**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o149.load. : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0**    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:38)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:45)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:45)   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createConnectionFactory(JdbcUtils.scala:45)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:120)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:91)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:57)     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Possible of duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Comment: It's because of JDK and JRE version mismatch..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Java version mismatch. The JDK and JRE should not be conflicting. If you are using JDk-1.8, use JRE 8

Comment: I have downgraded mysql jdbc connector version in spark configuration file and it's started working. Thanks for your help.